# Attempted import error: 'query' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner please help, I tried to find a solution to this but nothing works.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {query, where} from "firebase/firestore";

import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAKLyeY2FbjFDD57Kp9sGDi8uHg3neXxjI",
  authDomain: "digitots-dev.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "digitots-dev",
  storageBucket: "digitots-dev.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "150130182744",
  appId: "1:150130182744:web:4aba8f8c3b54a74f94182d",
  measurementId: "G-NHKFKD97C5"
})
```

The error is

> Attempted import error: 'query' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'.

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "digitots",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "animated-number-react": "^0.1.2",
    "firebase": "^9.0.0",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-countup": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried npm i firebase@9.0.0 now it has this error:

> Attempted import error: 'firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase').

Comment: Version 9.16.6 :)

Comment: I tried npm i firebase@9.0.0 and it has this error

Comment: Attempted import error: 'firebase/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebase').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the just released `v9` SDK, there is no longer a global `firebase` export. Instead you'll need to import each individual function that your code uses. As shown in the documentation for [initializing the modular v9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9), that looks like:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});

const db = getFirestore();
```

Since you seem more comfortable (or be using a tutorial) with the older v8 API, you can also continue use that - or use the `compat` layer in v9. The syntax for that would be:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Using the `compat` layer won't get you nearly as much of the size advantage of the new version, but it'll allow you to get started quickly, and then migrate to the new syntax (and the associated size difference) incrementally.

I recommend checking out:

- The blog post on [the new modular JavaScript SDK (v9)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/the-new-firebase-js-sdk-now-ga.html)
- The [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for the modular SDK

Comment: Thanks you so much! :)

Comment: You're welcome @PathonScript  Be sure to read the links too, as the changes are *quite* extensive and most information outside of firebase.google.com is likely going to refer to the old/compat APIs for quite some time.

Comment: I will! I didn't know about the update before encountering this.